# Are `if model.variable` and `unless model.variable.nil?` equivalent?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

There are two if-statements to evaluate whether the object is `nil`.

Method: A

```
if object
  blahblahblah
end
```

Method: B

```
unless object.nil?
  blahblahblah
end
```

Are A and B identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the `false` case as stated in [@Sergio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44241346/2423164), your object might not have a `#nil?` method. For example:

```
BasicObject.new.nil?
  # !> NoMethodError: undefined method `nil?' for #<BasicObject:0x007fd0aa21d270>
```

Still, in 99+% of the cases, there is no difference.

---

Not making an explicit `nil?` check however is considered more idiomatic and is less confusing (as the alternative is almost a double negation).

Answer (score 1):

> Are A and B identical?

No, they are not. First one also checks if `object` is `false`.